# Comprobar si un substring se encuentra en un string C++

Tags: c++, string

Estoy haciendo un trabajo que me pide que encuentre un substring en un string. Al enviar el programa, me dice el siguiente error:

> ```
> Failed example:
>     <br>printf 'hello how are you\nbye' | ./program
> <br>Expected: No, it does not exist
> <br>Got: Yes, it exists
> >
> ```

Aquí tenéis el código:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

bool substringExists(string s, string subs);

bool substringExists(string s, string subs){
    if (s.find(subs)){
      return true;
    }else{
    return (s.find(subs) != string::npos);
}
    }
int main(){
    string s1, s2;
  cin >> s1 >> s2;
  if (substringExists(s1, s2)){
    cout << "Yes, it exists";
                           }
  else{
    cout << "No, it does not exist";
      }
  return 0;
          }
```

Answer (score 1):

la función `substringExists()` debería tener sólo una condición:

```
bool
substringExists (string s, string subs)
{
  return s.find (subs) != string::npos;
}
```

Además, si quieres leer líneas completas, debes usar `getline()`:

```
int main(){
  string s1, s2;
  getline(cin, s1);
  getline(cin, s2);
  if (substringExists(s1, s2)){
    cout << "Yes, it exists";
                           }
  else{
    cout << "No, it does not exist";
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Saludos.

Comment: Mejoré esta respuesta. No sabía que querías leer líneas completas.